# MySQL slow query log bug? Logging quick queries

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-slow-query-log

I've setup MySQL slow query log pretty much default:

```
slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
```

When I look at the output, I notice it logging this query:

```
# Time: 180323  9:08:17
# User@Host: db_sys[db_sys] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 129753  Schema: pace-data  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 1.193407  Lock_time: 0.000040  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Rows_affected: 10
SET timestamp=1521792497;
REPLACE INTO `core_model_img` (`id_img`) VALUES ('848'), ('287'), ('311'), ('288'), ('289'), ('290'), ('291'), ('94'), ('292'), ('294');
```

It is inserting (or replacing) 10 rows in a 1 column table (the column is indexed). When I run the query myself, it takes 60ms. Yes, sometimes 65ms, but definitely nowhere near 1.194307 seconds.

Another odd thing is, the query seems to return at some odd interval (time UTC): 1:38:17, 2:08:17, 2:38:17, 5:08:17, 5:38:17, 6:08:17, 6:38:17, 8:38:17. This was during the night, while no real user activity was taking place.

The query could be indirectly invoked by something or someone (it is a web server), so this could be explainable, however: the main thing that puzzles me is the query time. I can't find out why it is logging this query. Could it be a bug?

(From Comment)

```
CREATE TABLE `core_model_img` (
    `id_img` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    UNIQUE KEY `id_img` (`id_img`), 
    CONSTRAINT `core_model_img_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_img`)
               REFERENCES `lib_img` (`id`)
               ON DELETE CASCADE
               ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It makes a _big_ difference whether the index is plain or `UNIQUE`.

Comment: ```CREATE TABLE `core_model_img` (
  `id_img` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_img` (`id_img`),
  CONSTRAINT `core_model_img_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_img`) REFERENCES `lib_img` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8```

Answer (score 0):

`REPLACE` is a combination of `DELETE` plus `INSERT`.

I wonder if the `DELETE` cascades before realizing that the `INSERT` is the same?  In which case, I worry that `REPLACE` and `FOREIGN KEYs` are incompatible.

Change`REPLACE` to `INSERT IGNORE`.